# Data rows indices start in 1 and not in 0, how can i change it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

Part of my csv file:

```
1,Afghanistan,2016,,,,
2,Albania,2006,22.899999618530305,,,
3,Albania,2009,,,
```

The code I used to load the data:

```
train_data = pd.read_csv(path_train, header=None, index_col=0)
train_data.columns = col_names
train_data.head(4)
```

col_names contains the list of my columns.
The output is:
[image: Data Image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures. Include your code and the data by pasting them into your question and format them using ctrl+k

Comment: This has to do with how the data is being read in so include that and a sample of your input file as well. It seems like you have an empty first row which could be dealt with when reading the file.

Comment: @pbreach No empty line there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Do `train_data.index.name = None` then display the dataframe again.

**More complete answer**:

It seems like the `0` you are referring to is not part of the index but rather the default index name. You can see this by checking the result of `train_data.index.name`. If you want to change this you could do:

```
train_data.index.name = "Index" # More meaningful index name
train_data.index.name = None  # Don't display additional row
```

But as far as the actual data is concerned there is no difference. You can see this by checking `train_data.values` and see that there is actually no empty row, and `train_data.index` shows that the index does start with `1`.

Comment: Thanks.
How can I completely remove the index column?

Comment: The index is part of the `DataFrame` and is used in the majority of operations that happen with them so it can't be removed. Better question is what makes you want to remove it?

Comment: I want to remove it because the indexes rearranged through the division to training and test

Comment: I think you could post that as another question about what you are trying to do with the dataframes that would make you want to remove the index. If you want the index to be ignored while doing division and the dataframes are the same shape you can do something like `df1 / df2.values`.